# Маршрутизация в проекте mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Есть проект на mvc. И у него разработан интерфейс под 2 браузера.
Соответственно сделано 2 мастер страницы. _layout для хрома и _layout.old для IE. В коде _ViewStart стандартный для всех проектов mvc код:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

При отладке смотрю, не важно в каком браузере я запускаю проект на эту строчку код заходит, а дальше уже если это хром то проект прыгает на новый интерфейс начиная со странички авторизации а если в explorer то на старый. Не могу понять где в проекте делается эта маршрутизация, как проект выбирает куда ему смотреть? Подскажите пожалуйста как это делаетя и где можно это поглядеть?

Comment: Посмотрите _ViewStart.cshtml либо поиском по именам layouts

Comment: @demonplus а вы мой вопрос точно внимательно прочитали? Там приведёт код вью старта. И по названиям мастер страниц я всё проискал, во всём проекте не нашёл что бы они встречались.

Comment: Тогда это магия :)

Comment: @demonplus спасибо за помощь...

Comment: Ну а браузер где-то определяется? Попробуйте поискать Request.Browser по всем файлам

Answer (score 0):

Гадание на кофейной гуще, но все же...

У контроллера есть одна из перегрузок метода метода [View](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.view?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Controller_View_System_String_System_String_System_Object_)

`protected internal virtual System.Web.Mvc.ViewResult View (string viewName, string masterName, object model);`

Как видно из сигнатуры, мы можем явно из кода задать нужную мастер-страницу.